# Permission denied: SCP from remote to local

Tags: macosx, amazon-ec2, aws

I have been trying to copy a folder from my remote server to my local and saw a lot of other questions and tried quite a few solutions there however no joy for me.

This is my command:

```
scp -r -i /Users/development/key.pem ec2-user@ip:/var/www/targetlocalfolder /Users/development/targetremotefolder
```

Verbose log as such

```
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:B7wHnM5MvhOy5PEYLGb0bHf/mPOgGIYFUzNYHBtzo5w
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/ec2-user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from xx
debug1: Host 'xx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ec2-user/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa (0x564298469010)
debug2: key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

key.pem CHMOD 400

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Lets try to go from local to server first, just to verify everything is working. That command is: scp -i (path of your key) (path for your file to be transferred) (username@ip):(path where file to be copied)

Comment: Also, the messages you are receiving (no such identity) are caused by using the wrong key, username or host as posted here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=145550

Comment: ```[ec2-user@ip-bbb-bbb-bbb-bbb ~]$ scp -i /Users/development/key.pem /Users/development/Desktop/somefolder/test.html ec2-user@aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa:/var/www/somefolder/

Warning: Identity file /Users/development/key.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.

Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection``` 

I am certain the pem key is on /Users/development folder. @jwcooper

Comment: ~ locate key.pem
/Users/development/key.pem

~ scp -i /Users/development/key.pem /Users/development/Desktop/somefolder/test.html ec2-user@remoteip:/var/www/destinationfolder

scp: /var/www/destinationfolder/test.html: Permission denied

Comment: Are you sure you have permissions on the target folder? Try to go to your instance and `chmod -R 777 /path/to/folder` .  That is going to open that folder (and all of its contents because you used the -R switch) up to anyone so make sure you change it back afterwords. I dont have a lot of experience with using scp on an AWS instance, but that message seems clear - it cant find/access the key. Keep trying that simple transfer, but maybe create a new key or move it somewhere else (assuming the permissions dont fix it).

Comment: folder on remote server is rwxr-xr- I think it's read and write. Thank you anyway @jwcooper, I will try again.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I can only SSH or do scp operation in the same terminal.
So solution for me is to have two terminals opened - one for SSH and other is for the scp.